# Pandas - df.at functionality error - python

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe, object

I'm trying to get pandas to write in a variable(that is a string) a certain cell in my dataframe at the end of a loop. I keep getting the below error.
code:

```
df1.at[i,'Status']=str(result)
```

Traceback Error:

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'example'
```

Is there any way to input non numeric values using the 'df.at' functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Columns `Status` dtype is `float`, so `at` assignment errors out when you assign string to it. You need convert it to dtype `object`

```
df1['Status'] = df1['Status'].astype(str)
df1.at[i,'Status'] = str(result)
```

Note: doing this all values in `Status` are converted to string.

Comment: This did the trick. Printed after to check and there it was. Although now i have to figure out why its not populating in excel should be a quick fix. Thanks for your help!